# Why MSVC14 allows declaring a pointer to a dynamic non-initialized const object?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

In "C++ Primer 5th edition", Chapter 12 "Dynamic memory and smart pointers" says:

> Like any other const, a dynamically allocated const object must be initialized. A const dynamic object of a class type that defines a default constructor (§ 7.1.4, p. 263) may be initialized implicitly. Objects of other types must be explicitly initialized. Because the allocated object is const, the pointer returned by new is a pointer to const (§ 2.4.2, p. 62).

So a statement like this is considered error:

```
const int* pi = new const int;
```

- If I run this statement on GCC, it fails to compile, but why does it compile on MSVC14?
- It looks to me like it is a stupid bug, the pointer is a pointer to `const`, which means there is no way to assign to it later, also accessing it is UB.

Comment: Non-standard compiler extension. (bug/feature)

Comment: MSVC isn't know for being the most conformant compiler.

Comment: Stupid from a programmer perspective? Yes. From a compiler perspective - not that much. Just another non-conformant behavior. `struct bar {}; new const bar;` compiles just fine.

Comment: No way?  Way: `*(const_cast<int*>(pi)) = 42;`

Comment: @HansPassant: I think it is undefined behavior in your example since using `const_cast` to cast away the constness of an originally constant object..

Comment: I checked before posting, not UB.

Comment: @HansPassant: But AFAIK using `const_cast` on pointers to const objects to change those objects is UB. isn't it??!!!

Comment: @HansPassant: This is from cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast

Comment: It is `new const int` that's the problem, that compilers accept that is a fair tragedy.  operator new is a library function, it doesn't know beans about burning PROMs.  Nor could it be told to do so.  But debating it is pointless,this is Jimmy code and you'd better use Git if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "bug" in MSVC because this is not the job of compiler but the runtime.

```
const int ci; // error ci is a constant object in Stack-memory so it must be initialized at compile-time.


const int* cpi; // ok. just a pointer to const. The compiler doesn't know whether you'll assign an initialized const object or not.

int choice = 0;
std::cin >> choice;
if(choice == arbitraryValue)
    cpi = new const int; // or cpi = new cont int(anotherArbitraryValue );
```

- As you can see it is allowed because at compile-time the compiler doesn't know how an object will be created and initialized at Runtime.
- It looks like you are asking:

  ```
  int a[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
  int index;
  cin >> index; // e.g: user enters 10
  cout << a[i];
  ```

Why the compiler allows using an out range index? Again because the compiler doesn't know about that runtime value; what it checks is only if the index type is related-type that can be used to access an array index.